# How to let muliple people use the command at the same time

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So I made a bot and one of the commands reqiures it to wait. While someone else is using that how do I let another user, use that command as well and not wait until the other person is finished?

```
if(command ==='rm'){
var hithere2 = message.content
var ret = hithere2.replace('-rm ','');
var result = ret.slice('&').split(',');
let remindercontent = result[0]
let remindertime = result[1]
if(!isNaN(remindertime)){

  if(remindertime % 1 == 0){
    message.channel.send({embed: {
      color: Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777214) + 1, 
      title: "Reminder set for " + remindercontent,
      description: 'It will go off in ' + remindertime + ' seconds',

    }})
    let sleeptime = remindertime * 1000
    
    sleep(sleeptime);

    message.channel.send('<@' + message.author.id + '>')
    message.channel.send({embed: {
      color: Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777214) + 1, 
      title: `BEEEP`,
      description: `${remindertime} seconds ago you wanted to remind yourself to **${remindercontent}**`,
    }})
    
  }
 }else {
  message.channel.send('Please enter a valid number after the comma!');
 }
```

Above is the command for the thing that I need to run simultaneously. I have the system-sleep mudule installed.

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: @Allister I added the code to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function? I'd usually consider using sleep() functions like that bad practise since you're stalling the thread.

Something like this might work for you (haven't tried this, you may need to pass arguments to that function):

```
setTimeout( function() {
      message.channel.send('<@' + message.author.id + '>')
      message.channel.send({embed: {
      color: Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777214) + 1, 
      title: `BEEEP`,
      description: `${remindertime} seconds ago you wanted to remind yourself to 
      **${remindercontent}**`,
       }})
}, sleeptime);
```

To show what a mean jj, here's a code snippet as an example:

```js
var commentInXMilliseconds = (delay) => {
  const text = "New time";
  setTimeout( function() {
    console.log(`${text} ${new Date()}`);
  }, delay);
}

console.log(`Start time: ${new Date()}`);
commentInXMilliseconds(2000);
```

Comment: How would I add how long I want it to wait, in my case `sleeptime`?

Comment: Yes, it's the time in milliseconds.

Comment: as in where would i put the variable.

Comment: Added in an example if that helps you, the timeout goes where i've put it, as the second paramter to setTimeout